# Group build targets in CMake project

Tags: cmake

I just included doxygen generation in my project using the *add_custom_target()* command. Now I did not include ALL as I don't want this build be default.

Now I have the following scenario.

project/subproj1/doc
project/subproj2/doc

In each subproject there is a CMakeLists.txt file with:
`add_custom_target(gen_doc_subproj1 ...)
add_custom_target(gen_doc_subproj2 ...)`

What I'd like to achieve is that after generating my make files I can type:

**make doc**
and it will build all documentation targets.

Is there some construction in CMake such as:
`if_not_exist_target_group(doc)
    create_target_group(doc)
    endif
    add_to_target_group(gen_doc_subproj1, doc)`

Any pointers would be appriciated.

Comment: Did you try to create empty list in main `CMakeLists.txt`, fill it in sub cmake files, and after all `add_subdirectory` output it with `message(STATUS "${mylist}")` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If i understood you right, it is as simple as

```
if(NOT TARGET doc)
  add_custom_target(doc)
  add_dependencies(doc gen_doc_subproj1 gen_doc_subproj2 ...)
endif()
```

Comment: Hello,

This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it should not be that difficult to implement with CMake.

Thank you for your response.